# I need raw read data from and write data into drive..help

Tags: c, linux

I need raw read data from and write data into drive..not via existed filesystem like fat32 or something....i just wanna raw write read......
I was told in Windows i can use CreateFile WriteFile and ReadFile APIs to access data in drive directly... but I dont know in Linux whether there r similar functions....

dont tell me to use hardware driver programming, coz i am just a newbie in linux programming..
thanx a lot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files `/dev/hd*` and `/dev/sd*`, depending on your setup, contain raw disk data. You need `root` account usually.

Use `mount` command to find out which disks/partitions are mapped to which files.

Comment: But what r the functions? r they still like read() and write?

Comment: @Macroideal: yes. open/read/write should behave much the same as when used on regular files. For the most part on linux/unix, everything is a file.

Comment: i think you can also modify the permissions for those devices and use them as a normal user

you'll need to unmount that device before reading or writing to it directly.

Comment: Macroideal, is "r" a verb? If so, what does it mean? I'm sorry, English is not my native language and my dictionary doesn't have it.

Comment: @liori, "r" is a contraction of "are".